# Does "there's nothing like (something)" always imply something very good? Or, not always the case?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Many dictionaries define the phrase "*there's nothing like*" as something like the following.

> used to say that a particular thing is very enjoyable (From [Longman
> Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/there-s-nothing-like))

> a general expression of praise (From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/theres-nothing-like))

In some cases, however, the phrase is being used in a negative tone as seen in the following example.

> *There is nothing like* a person who seems disinterested in the issue
> that a customer is experiencing. (From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-should-be-the-proper-phone-etiquette-customer-service) Q&A website.)

Apparently, there is a contradiction between the definitions in the dictionaries I quoted and the actual usage in the above example.

Can I assume that the usage of the phrase like the above example just one of rare exceptions?

Comment: Perhaps less a exception than an ironic use of the phrase.

Comment: I'm reminded of Alice and the Red King (_Through the Looking-Glass_ by Lewis Carroll, who was a mathematician and interested in logic). The King says "There's nothing like eating hay when you're fainting." Alice suggests some better remedies." 'I didn't say there was nothing BETTER,' the King replied. `I said there was nothing LIKE it.' Which Alice did not venture to deny."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "Peter" in the comments analyzed this correctly.  This is ironic; the person is the best at being bad. It is rather unusual.  Note that the use of "disinterested" is also unusual; "disinterested" normally means "unbiased".

Comment: That interpretation didn't come up to my mind at all. I can't help but feel how poor my English comprehension is. Just one more question. One of my English-Japanese dictionaries takes an example sentence saying "*There is nothing like a person who always asks for a loan.*" How do you read this? Is it also ironic, or is it just a weird sentence?

Comment: You can't tell irony from the words.  You have to look at the full context.  Is "there is nothing... for a loan" part of a conversation in which the person is generally critical of people who ask for loans?  Then it must be ironic.  You listen to the tone of voice and read the body language.  Culturally some people use irony more often, English people more so than Americans.  Japanese frequently uses irony too (in my experience)  Consider  "Omae" or "Kisama" and explain how these are not extremely polite.